# Is possible with nc or telnet affect a socket

Tags: sockets, tcp, telnet, netcat

I have a conceptual question.

If I have a Java socket (this socket stablish a TCP connection by a channel)

If I run a nc command, the nc command open a tcp connection, then the nc can affect my socket

The same question with telnet, is possible that the telnet affect my socket connection?

Answer (score 1):

Not normally.  The operating system will keep those sockets separate.  You won't easily affect one socket from another.

If your Java application uses local port 10001 to connect to an HTTPS server on port 443, that socket would be dedicated to that connection between those IPs and ports.  IF netcat  from the same machine connected to the same server on 443, it wouldn't use the same local ports, and they would not be the same socket.

Now, in unixland at least, open sockets are just file descriptors, and those can be passed between programs.  So, for example, your Java application can spawn a new thread and hand the open socket to the thread.  But an independent process on the system can't easily just nab data from the open socket.

Of course, these limitations are merely enforced in software, not physical laws, so "anything is possible".  But operating systems are going to try to stop this kind of thing from happening.